# Thread panicking when simulating keypresses in using enigo

Tags: rust, runtime-error

I am currently trying to write a program in rust, that simulates pressing the 'Windows+D' shortcut in rust, so I can switch to the desktop by starting this program.
To do this, I've come up with this simple script that doesn't work (obviously):

main.rs:

```rs
fn main() {
    use std::env;
    env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "1");
    use enigo::*;

    let mut enigo = Enigo::new();

    enigo.key_down(Key::Meta);
    enigo.key_click(Key::Layout('d'));
    enigo.key_up(Key::Meta);
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```toml
[package]
name = "win_plus_d"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
enigo='0.0.14'
```

The program compiles, but after running, I get an error that I, as someone new to rust, don't understand. I've tried googling about this with many different search queries, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Output after 'cargo run' in the project folder:

```
   Compiling win_plus_d v0.1.0 (C:\[redacted]\win_plus_d)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.50s
     Running `.\win_plus_d.exe`
thread 'main' panicked at 'cannot transmute_copy if U is larger than T', /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52\library\core\src\mem\mod.rs:1057:5
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\std\src\panicking.rs:584
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52/library\core\src\panicking.rs:142
   2: core::mem::transmute_copy<winapi::um::winuser::KEYBDINPUT,winapi::um::winuser::INPUT_u>
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52\library\core\src\mem\mod.rs:1057
   3: enigo::win::win_impl::keybd_event
             at C:\Users\Quoneel\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\enigo-0.0.14\src\win\win_impl.rs:36
   4: enigo::win::win_impl::impl$1::key_down
             at C:\Users\Quoneel\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\enigo-0.0.14\src\win\win_impl.rs:138
   5: win_plus_d::main
             at C:\Users\Quoneel\Projects\Rust\win_plus_d\src\main.rs:9
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<void (*)(),tuple$<> >
             at /rustc/a55dd71d5fb0ec5a6a3a9e8c27b2127ba491ce52\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:248
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
error: process didn't exit successfully: `.\win_plus_d.exe` (exit code: 101)
```

I think this means that there is a bug in the 'enigo' cargo (I'm not exactly sure), so a work-around would be much appreciated.

I have tried some things that didn't make any difference:

- using an upper-case 'D' in `enigo.key_click(Key::Layout('d'));`
- removing `enigo.key_down(Key::Meta);` and `enigo.key_up(Key::Meta);`
- removing `enigo.key_click(Key::Layout('d'));` instead

Removing these three lines (

```rs
enigo.key_down(Key::Meta);
enigo.key_click(Key::Layout('d'));
enigo.key_up(Key::Meta);
```

) worked, so I think that they are the issue.

I have also already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70251830/how-to-press-keys-with-enigo-in-rust), but I am not advanced enough to understand if I can find an answer there.
Let me know if any additional info is needed. I would be very thankful for any help to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in enigo (it uses the [`transmute_copy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute_copy.html) function wrongly). There is [only one place](https://github.com/enigo-rs/enigo/blob/5bb84e938009385987875472adafaa45613b3534/src/win/win_impl.rs#L36) they call this function, so it must be there. I'd suggest filling a bug.

Comment: There's actually an API to switch to the desktop: [`Shell.ToggleDesktop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-toggledesktop) ([`IShellDispatch4.ToggleDesktop` in the `windows` crate](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/Shell/struct.IShellDispatch4.html#method.ToggleDesktop)]. You'd have to look up how to do the `CreateObject` in Rust though...

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug in `enigo`: there is [an open issue about it](https://github.com/enigo-rs/enigo/issues/121) and [an open PR to solve it](https://github.com/enigo-rs/enigo/pull/122).

Until it is merged, you need to patch the crate to use this PR. See [Overriding Dependencies - The Cargo Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) for how to.